# Pass value using FB UI and get in controller

Tags: php, facebook, zend-framework

its the function i used to pass the value,there id is the value that am passing.but its not getting on the method i used.how can i get it correctly

---

```
$(document).on('click','.buy-coins',function(){
                    var url=window.location.origin;
                    var requestID = hash(64);
                    console.log("Constructing Request ID: " + requestID);
                    var id = $(this).attr('value');
                    $('#purchased_coin_count').attr('value',$(this).attr('coins'));
                    FB.ui({
                        method: 'pay',
                        action: 'purchaseitem',
                        product: url+"/index/coinpurchase/"+id,//here i pass the id
                        request_id: requestID,
                        quantity: 1
                    },
```

---

then i tried to retrieve it using

---

```
 $packId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

---

but its not working,how can i get the value of id that i am passing

Answer (score 1):

Pass ID like this:

```
product: url+"/index/coinpurchase/?id="+id
```

Comment: check the values being passed in Firebug and echo `$this->_getAllParams()` to see all params being passed into the request